# Approximate Speed-Up With Increasing Cores?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, gurobi

First off: I totally understand if "it depends" is the only feasible solution.

I'm running a large (to me) MIP using Gurobi in R on my local machine.  (~2M binary decision variables, ~15K continuous decision variables).

I have 256GB RAM and the model is only using about 40GB at max, during presolve, so that's not a bottleneck.  My processor is puny though, only 4 cores and 4 threads.  I'm awaiting delivery for a 18 core / 36 thread processor.  Assuming I run the model on 35 of the 36 threads, on approximately what order of a speedup can I anticipate?  I'm assuming there's a diminishing returns with more cores.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that anyone can give a meaningful answer. The speedup is definitely a sublinear function of the number of cores or number of threads, and is also problem-specific (and solver-specific).

Regarding the new processor, there are a couple of things to keep in mind. One is processor speed. More cores is nice, but if the processor is slower than your current one the net gain will obviously be lower. Another is memory. I'm not a Gurobi user, but I would bet it is similar to CPLEX in this regard. When the solver ropes in a new core/thread, it creates a (partial?) copy of the constraint matrix and related stuff for that thread to use. So your RAM usage goes up, I think more or less linearly, with the number of threads in play. RAM may not be the limiting factor on your current box, but it could become the roadblock on your new box unless the new box boasts a proportionally bigger amount of memory.

Comment: Thanks @prubin.  Unfortunately the new processor is slightly slower (2.4 GHz vs. 2.8 GHz) but my options were limited with the additional cores.  I'm just going to swap out the processor on my current box which is maxed out at 256GB RAM.  We'll see

Comment: When you've swapped in the new processor, I would suggest test runs starting with a limit of maybe 15 to 20 threads and then work your way up gradually. I think I've heard of people either crashing the OS or slowing their PCs to a serious crawl (making it hard for the user to interact with the system) by running too many threads with too large a model.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll be sure to do that.

Answer (score 3):

“It depends” absolutely is the answer and while I won’t give you any numbers, I might provide a brief insight into on what it could depend:

Whereas continuous LPs gain little from more cores (Gurobi runs several barrier algorithms in parallel per default, but for the simplex method, parallelization is a [niche](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/hall/HiGHS/)), MIP algorithms are typically branch-and-bound based. This allows to process parts of the B&B tree in parallel. As visualized very well in ["Branching rules revisited" by Achterberg, Koch, Martin in Operations Research Letters, Volume 33, Issue 1](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167637704000501), such B&B trees could be deep and thin or well balanced. The former will be hard to parallelize, while the latter scale quite well.

One example: If you branch on a binary variable $v_1$ you create one branch where $v_1=0$ is fixed and another where $v_1=1$ is fixed. Assume that of all the variables $v_1 ... v_{100000}$ at most/exactly one variable can be 1, all others zero. In this case, the branch where $v_1=1$ is fixed implicitly also fixes $v_2 ... v_{100000}$, which reduced the problem by a lot, so this subtree will be small. On the other hand, $v_1=0$ does not provide much new information, so you would likely branch on $v_2$ with the same effect: $v_2=0$ is almost no news, whereas $v_2=1$ implicitly fixes all the other variables, so this will be a small subtree again. Thus, situations where only one/few variables from a large set of variables can be set/unset and all other variables have to have the opposite value, you are likely to get a deep and thin tree which is hard to parallelize efficiently.

If you want to see some speedup numbers from GuRoBi and other ideas, I'd recommend [this presentation](https://cdn.gurobi.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/How-to-Exploit-Parallelism-in-Linear-and-Mixed-Integer-Programming.pdf) from page 26 on.

Comment: Thanks.  It's a MIP but I can't speak to the B&B tree structure...